# How do I set the size of the MediaView so that all videos fit in the scene and can grow proportionally to the scene?

Tags: java, javafx

At the same time, so that the videos fit entirely into the scene. This code is an attempt to fit three videos in a scene.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainListener extends Application {

    public static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 3;
    public static String current_directory;

    Button btnPlay = new Button("Play");

    ArrayList<MediaBox> mediaBoxes = new ArrayList<MediaBox>();
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,dimension.getWidth()/2, dimension.getHeight()/2);
        getPathToWorkDirectory();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++){
            MediaBox mediaBox = new MediaBox(i+1);
            mediaBoxes.add(mediaBox);
            flowPane.getChildren().add(mediaBox);
        }

        setActions();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlay, flowPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void setActions() {
        btnPlay.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                for (MediaBox mediaBox : mediaBoxes) {
                    mediaBox.getMediaPlayer().play();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public static void getPathToWorkDirectory(){
        current_directory = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(current_directory);
    }
}
```

Media View for channel. I understand that you need to use DoubleProperty to resize proportionally. But at the same time, I don’t understand how to correctly bind the scene size to the VBox node, and then bind all MediaView elements to VBox

```
class MediaBox extends MediaView {
    private String path;
    private Media media;

    public MediaBox(Integer num_channel){
        //Path to video
        path = MainListener.current_directory + "\\ch_" + num_channel.toString() + ".mp4";
        media = new Media(pathToURL(path));

        DoubleProperty mvw = fitWidthProperty();
        DoubleProperty mvh = fitHeightProperty();

        mvw.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(sceneProperty(), "width"));
        mvh.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(sceneProperty(), "height"));

        setMediaPlayer(new MediaPlayer(media));
    }
    private String pathToURL(String src_path) {
        File file = new File(src_path);
        String out_path = null;

        try {
            out_path = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException mURL_E) {
            System.out.println("Error in path URL for video");
        }
        return out_path;
    }
}
```

The video goes beyond the window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAIzn.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fUPt.jpg)

Comment: Don’t write this: `import java.awt.*` and use the awt `Toolkit`.  JavaFX has `Screen` classes to get screen information if you really need it.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using bindings for layout tasks. Favor using standard layout panes, and if none do what you need (which in general is unlikely), create a custom layout pane by overriding `layoutChildren()`.

To add resizability to non-resizable nodes, such as `ImageView` and `MediaView`, wrap them in a `Region` and use the API of that node to resize them to the region's size.

Create a custom `Region` that holds a `MediaView` and resizes the `MediaView` to the region's size:

```
public class MediaBox extends Region {

    private final MediaView mediaView ;

    public MediaBox(MediaView mediaView) {
        this.mediaView = mediaView ;
        getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();
        mediaView.setFitWidth(width);
        mediaView.setFitHeight(height);
        Bounds mvBounds = mediaView.getBoundsInLocal();
        mediaView.relocate((width-mvBounds.getWidth())/2, (height-mvBounds.getHeight())/2);
    }
}
```

You may need to override the `computePrefWidth(...)`, `computePrefHeight(...)` methods as well, to get the desired behavior.

Now you can just wrap your `MediaView`s in this `MediaBox` and use any normal layout strategy:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    Rectangle2D dimension = screen.getBounds();
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, dimension.getWidth()/2, dimension.getHeight()/2);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++){
        String url = Paths.get(
          System.getProperty("user.dir"), 
          "ch_"+i+".mp4"
        ).toURI().toString();
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(
            new MediaPlayer(
                new Media(url)
            )
        );
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        MediaBox mediaBox = new MediaBox(mediaView);
        mediaBoxes.add(mediaBox);
        flowPane.getChildren().add(mediaBox);
    }

    setActions();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlay, flowPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with what you suggested. But I still had a problem with resizing the MediaView depending on the size of the Scene, I added a little of myself and something worked, but I don’t understand if I made the right decision.Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code you left. But I still have a problem with changing the size of the `Region` depending on the Scene. I added `scene.widthProperty.addListener()` and `scene.heigthProperty.addListener()` to solve this problem and it worked. But is this approach correct?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainListener extends Application {

    public static final int NUM_CHANNELS = 6;

    Button btnPlay = new Button("Play");
    ArrayList<MediaBox> mediaBoxes = new ArrayList<MediaBox>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D dimension = screen.getBounds();
        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, dimension.getWidth(), dimension.getHeight());

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++){
            String url = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"ch_" + (i+1) + ".mp4").toUri().toString();
            System.out.println(url);
            MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(
                    new MediaPlayer(
                            new Media(url)
                    )
            );

            mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            MediaBox mediaBox = new MediaBox(mediaView);

            scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {
                    mediaBox.setPrefHeight(number.doubleValue()/4);
                    System.out.println("Height: " + number);
                }
            });

            scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {
                    mediaBox.setPrefWidth(number.doubleValue()/4);
                    System.out.println("Width: " + number);
                }
            });
            mediaBoxes.add(mediaBox);
            flowPane.getChildren().add(mediaBox);
        }
        setActions();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlay, flowPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void setActions() {
        btnPlay.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                for(MediaBox mediaBox : mediaBoxes){
                    mediaBox.getMediaView().getMediaPlayer().play();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here I have set only the `setMinSize(300,400)` and add `getMediaView()`

```
class MediaBox extends Region{
    private final MediaView mediaView;

    public MediaBox(MediaView mediaView){
        this.mediaView = mediaView;
        layoutChildren();
        getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(){

        setMinSize(300, 400);

        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();

        mediaView.setFitHeight(height);
        mediaView.setFitWidth(width);
        Bounds mvBounds = mediaView.getBoundsInLocal();
        mediaView.relocate((width-mvBounds.getWidth()/2), (height-mvBounds.getHeight())/2);
    }
    public MediaView getMediaView(){
        return mediaView;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTasZ.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer or not; if you're asking for clarification you should either edit the question or leave a comment. But registering listeners with the scene's dimensions and updating the sizing hints is never a good approach.  I'm not really clear exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but it should be achievable by placing the media boxes in an appropriate layout pane with appropriate settings.

Comment: My task was that I have 6 videos, but they did not all fit in the window, and at the same time they did not change their size depending on the size of the window.